# Autocorrelation and Confidence Intervals

Tags: machine-learning

I was reading the Regression chapter of ISLR and could not understand the following line.

"If in fact there
is correlation among the error terms, then the estimated standard errors
will tend to underestimate the true standard errors."

How is correlation among the error terms going to underestimate the standard errors and there by confidence intervals? Please note that I am new to statistics and statistical learning.

Could you please help me with an explanation.

Thanks,
G Ravi Kiran.

Comment: I think the question is best-suited for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)